# How to separated multi delimited data and concatenate in one column

Tags: sql

I have a table data like this :

```
Id  NAME

1   Cleo Bond;Smith Brian;James Jiff Bond;Alice; Gray Tin Ronald Downell
```

I want to separate the semicolon delimited string,  remove all space, take the initial character from each name then concatenate the values with space. 
Output Should be like :

```
Id  Name  

1   CB SM JJB A GTRD
```

How can i do this?

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Tag only with the database you are using.

Comment: Why is it `SM` and not `SB` (Smith Brian)?

Comment: Sorry it's must be SB.

Answer (score 0):

You should **never ever** store more than one value in one cell!

character separated lists are a pain in the neck...

Further more: Please do not poste a SQL related question without stating your actual RDBMS (oracle, SQL Server, MySQL, other) and its version!

This solution will need various string operations. Each RDBMS works differently, although there is some *common sense*.

The following is a SQL-Server approach. You will get the direction...

I use an inline splitter via XML (there are many ways / functions / tools to find!) first to split the string at semicolons, than the parts at blanks. The first letters are re-concatenated. First just *as is*, in the second step all together with a blank:

```
DECLARE @mockup TABLE(Id INT,NAME VARCHAR(1000));
INSERT INTO @mockup VALUES
 (1,'Cleo Bond;Smith Brian;James Jiff Bond;Alice; Gray Tin Ronald Downell');

WITH Names AS
(
    SELECT m.Id
          ,m.NAME
          ,C_Key
          ,LEFT(UPPER(F.NamePart.value(N'text()[1]','nvarchar(max)')),1) AS Initial
    FROM @mockup AS m
    CROSS APPLY(SELECT m.NAME
                      ,CAST('<x>' + REPLACE((SELECT m.NAME AS [*] FOR XML PATH('')),';','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML)) AS A(A_Key,AllParts)
    CROSS APPLY A.AllParts.nodes(N'/x[text()]') AS B(Part)
    CROSS APPLY(SELECT B.Part.value(N'text()[1]',N'nvarchar(max)')
                      ,CAST('<y>' + REPLACE((SELECT B.Part.value(N'text()[1]',N'nvarchar(max)') AS [*] FOR XML PATH('')),' ','</y><y>') + '</y>' AS XML)) AS C(C_Key,PersParts)
    CROSS APPLY C.PersParts.nodes(N'/y[text()]') AS D(PersPart)
    CROSS APPLY(SELECT D.PersPart.value(N'text()[1]',N'nvarchar(max)')
                      ,CAST('<z>' + REPLACE((SELECT D.PersPart.value(N'text()[1]',N'nvarchar(max)') AS [*] FOR XML PATH('')),' ','</z><z>') + '</z>' AS XML)) AS E(E_Key,NameParts)
    CROSS APPLY E.NameParts.nodes('/z[text()]') AS F(NamePart)
)
,AllInitials AS
(
    SELECT outerN.Id
          ,outerN.NAME
          ,outerN.C_Key
          ,(SELECT innerN.Initial AS [*] FROM Names AS innerN WHERE innerN.C_Key=outerN.C_Key FOR XML PATH('')) AS Initials
    FROM Names AS outerN
    GROUP BY Id,NAME,C_Key
)
SELECT outerAI.Id
      ,outerAI.NAME
      ,STUFF((SELECT ' ' + innerAI.Initials AS [*] FROM AllInitials AS innerAI WHERE innerAI.Id=outerAI.Id FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') AS Initials
FROM AllInitials AS outerAI
GROUP BY outerAI.Id,outerAI.NAME;
```

I must admit, that I did this just for fun... This solution is ugly and erronous (two different persons with the same name, illegal characters, NULLs)... I would never try to solve this in *real life* with an approach like this. Try to change the original data first!

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution for Postgres:

```
-- prepare test data
create table data (id integer, name text);
insert into data (id, name)
values (1,'Cleo Bond;Smith Brian;James Jiff Bond;Alice; Gray Tin Ronald Downell');
```

```
select id, string_agg(initials, ' ') as names
from (
  select id, string_agg(left(w.word, 1),'' order by n) initials
  from data, 
       unnest(string_to_array(name, ';')) with ordinality  as n(names, n),
       unnest(string_to_array(n.names, ' ')) as w(word)
  where nullif(trim(w.word), '') is not null
  group by id, n
) t
group by id;
```

Online example: http://rextester.com/HFDBW27664

But that is a horrible data model, you should really normalize this.